# Creating a socket in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, swift3

I'm having trouble creating a socket in Swift 3. The problem is that I cannot reference "NULL" in the following command:

```
ipv4Socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, kCFSocketAutomaticallyReenableAcceptCallBack, socketCallback, NULL)
```

I've tried to replace `NULL` with `CFNULL`, `NSNull`, etc, but have had no success. How do I create an `UnsafeRawPointer<CFSocketContext!>` with a `NULL` value?

Comment: What does this have to do with `c`?

Comment: The type of the last parameter is `UnsafePointer<CFSocketContext>!`. Why don't you simply pass `nil`?

Comment: `nil` worked...I was overthinking it.

@ScottHunter - This is a C-level API in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

`nil` worked...I was overthinking it.
                    – Jake